# How to render a background image in my index.html to make it dynamic using Django?

Tags: html, django, templates, jinja2, backend

I'm trying to make a template dynamic. I added the jinja pattern wherever required and it worked except for the background images of the page.

I tried this:

```
    <div class="background_image" style="background-image:url({% static 'images/travello.jpg' %})"></div>
```

I expected to see the bg_image on the page, but i get nothing except blank white space. I get other images in the same folder using:

```
    <img src="{% static 'images/destination_4.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

Comment: missing the code you tried

Comment: use the inspector of your browser and see what is rendered

Comment: you need to enclose the url in single quotes to obtain `url('/static/path/to/images/im.jpg')`. If you look at the source code in your browser inspector you'll see the quotes are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Just add static in front of the image url such as the following

```
<div class="background_image" style="background-image:url(static/images/travello.jpg)"></div>
```